# Emit data from child and add it Parent Array

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass an input text data from child component to Parent.

Passed data then added to the array of objects.

Using *ngFor i'm displaying all the array objects.

Issue is, newly added value is empty only empty li is getting added

Console Issue:

[image]

App Component.

```js
const HEROES: Herotype[] = [{
    name: 'Mr. Nice'
  },
  {
    name: 'Narco'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bombasto'
  }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tours of Hero';
  heroes = HEROES;
  myFav = this.heroes[0];

  selectedHero: string;

  onclick(hero: string) {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
    console.log(this.selectedHero)
  }

  newAddedHero($event) {
    this.heroes.push($event)
    // console.log (this.heroes.push($event));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>My Favorite hero is <b>{{myFav.name}}</b></h2>

  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onclick(hero)">
      {{hero.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <app-addhero (newHero)="newAddedHero($event)"></app-addhero>
</div>
```

Add Hero Component

```js
export class AddheroComponent implements OnInit {

  addedHero: string;

  @Output() newHero = new EventEmitter < string > ();

  addHero(value) {
    this.addedHero = value;
    this.newHero.emit(this.addedHero)
    console.log(this.addedHero);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you also add the code of `app-addhero` component?

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: In your code what is the value of console.log(this.addedHero);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are passing there just a `string`, instead of `Herotype`. Try it like this:

```
newAddedHero(name) {
  this.heroes.push(new Herotype({name}));
}
```

Or just:

```
newAddedHero(name) {
  this.heroes.push({name});
}
```

`{name}` is ES6 shorthand for `{name: name}`. You can name your method parameter as you wish, so I renamed it to `name` to use this shorthand.

Comment: I'm getting an[ts] Argument of type '{ name: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
 error like this ""

Comment: newAddedHero(name) {
  this.heroes.push({name});
} this is working

Comment: Sounds like Herotype has constructor that want just the name, not sure as you did not provided that implementation.